# Python small brute-forcer

Tags: python, optimization, combinatorics

I have 20+ key set. Keyset is like:

```
Key[0] = { "PossibleKey0", "PossibleKey0Another", "AnotherPossibleKey0" }
Key[1] = { ....
```

There is an encryption which needs to be broken, it will receive 20+ keys, one after another. So it applies decryption one-by-one.

So `key[0]` has 3 different possible keys, same for `key[1]`, `key[2]`, etc.

I should try each key with its each possible keys. I decided to write it like:

```
for i in range(0, len(Key[0])):
    for j in range(0, len(Key[1])):
        for k in range(0, len(Key[2])):
            for l in range(0, len(Key[2])):
                Decrypt(Key[0][i], Key[1][j], Key[2][k], Key[3][l])
```

But it looks OK for small key sets, what's better approach when there will be 20+ keys?

Comment: What is `Key` - a list? Where is `Decrypt` defined? Is e.g. `key1` the same as `Key[1]` (or `Key[0]`)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Key is a two dimensional list, each entry in Key list, have an array of strings, from key[x], one should be used, then from next one ( key[x+1] ) one should be used, but we have to try ALL possible keys, but we never use 2 keys from same key[x].

Comment: It's a `set` of strings, not an array. And the answers to my other questions?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Decrypt is a Python function I've written, it will receive list of keys (as much as possible) and try to apply algorithm one after another

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, key1 is Key[1]. That code was just a pseudo code to demonstrate what I mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to factor out nested loops, and tuple unpacking with `*` to neatly deal with multiple arguments:

```
from itertools import product

for keys in product(*Key):
    Decrypt(*keys)
```

A simple example:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> keys = ["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"]
>>> for k in product(*keys):
    print k


('a', 'c', 'e', 'g')
('a', 'c', 'e', 'h')
('a', 'c', 'f', 'g')
('a', 'c', 'f', 'h')
('a', 'd', 'e', 'g')
('a', 'd', 'e', 'h')
('a', 'd', 'f', 'g')
('a', 'd', 'f', 'h')
('b', 'c', 'e', 'g')
('b', 'c', 'e', 'h')
('b', 'c', 'f', 'g')
('b', 'c', 'f', 'h')
('b', 'd', 'e', 'g')
('b', 'd', 'e', 'h')
('b', 'd', 'f', 'g')
('b', 'd', 'f', 'h')
```

Note that for four sets of 20 keys, there would be 160,000 combinations (`20 ** 4 == 160000`).

Comment: Thanks! But how about when I want to use one entry from each key[x], then again one from key[x+1]?

Comment: Have you actually *looked* at the example? That is what `product` does, it will give you all possible combinations of keys picking one from each `set` in `Key`.

Comment: Let me try it and I'll comeback (15 mins), thank you!